# Initial value of a dictionary while handling forms with a class-based view

Tags: python, django

I read the Class-Based View page in the Django documentation site and I stumbled with this code example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from .forms import MyForm

class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My question is why I should create the `initial = {'key': 'value'}` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The `initial` attribute is not mandatory. It's default value is an empty dictionary. You would use it if you want to pre-populate  fields in your form, maybe because that's what the majority of user's would select. For example if you have a field named `country`, you can set `initial = {'country':'USA'}` to populate that field for the user as the view is rendered.